# What is the proof that $\sum \limits_{v \in V} deg(v) = 2|E|$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

My textbook gives $\sum \limits_{v \in V} deg(v) = 2|E|$ and has the proof

> If an edge is not a loop it gets counted twice b/c it's incident with
>   2 different vertices. If an edge is a loop, by convention it has
>   degree 2.

I think this proof is wrong because edges don't have degree, vertices do. Even if edges do have degrees, it seems like this proof is missing something, for example in no way does it explain the relation between degrees and number of edges. I struggle a lot with proofs, and knowing when something is considered proved.

Comment: Just use the double counting strategy. You will find something like $\sum deg(u)=$#$S$ and $2|E|=$#$S$.

Comment: I don't know double counting strategy

Comment: You are right that the last line of the proof is misleading: for now, ignore that final sentence, and ignore the case of graphs with loops — imagine that your graph has no loops. Further, note that the degree of a vertex is the number of edges incident on that vertex. So $\sum_{v\in V} d(v)$ is the sum over every vertex of the number of edges it is incident to. That is the relation between

Comment: @Celeritas this strategy is exactly what i wrote. Compute $\sum deg(u)$ and compute $2|E|$. The computations are two,so it's double counting.

Comment: You can also prove this by induction on the number of edges if you're any more comfortable with that type of proof, but it is much less efficient than double counting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that an edge has a "degree."  It's that any edge *connects two vertices*.

If you go through a graph counting the degree of each vertex, what are you counting?  Are you counting anything twice?

Comment: I think the given proof (assuming it has been quoted correctly by the OP) is also at fault, for ending with the line "If an edge is a loop, by convention it has degree 2" which can get confusing.